# How to proxy HTTPS traffic with burp suite?

Tags: python, sockets, ssl, https, burp

I have a website which is available at: https://abs:8443/myweb
I use burp suite as a local proxy:

```
proxyIP = "127.0.0.1"
proxyPort = 8080
```

Then I tried to proxy the https trafic via burp to the https website but it failed. Here is what I tried:

```
import sys
import socket
import ssl
import os

url = "https://abs:8443/myweb"
proxyIP = "127.0.0.1"
proxyPort = 8080
targetIP = "abs"
context = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1)
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s_sock = context.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname=targetIP)
s_sock.connect((proxyIP, proxyPort))

data = "some data"

payload = (
    "POST "+url+" HTTP/1.1\r\n"
    "Host: "+targetIP+":8443\r\n"
    "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686; rv:52.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/52.0\r\n"
    "Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8\r\n"
    "Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5\r\n"
    "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate\r\n"
    "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n"
    "Content-Length: "+str(len(data))+"\r\n"
    "\r\n" + data + "\r\n"
)

sock.sendall(payload)
recv = sock.recv(64000)
sock.close()
print recv
```

**How to proxy HTTPS traffic with burp suite?**

Comment: To proxy HTTPS traffic you first need to send a CONNECT request to the proxy, then initiate an SSL tunnel. Rather than deal with this raw, you're probably better using an HTTP library like requests which handles this for you.

Comment: Could you please provide a full answer?

Answer (score 0):

You will need a normal listener, such as 127.0.0.1:8080  -  Then you will have to install the burp CA certificate in order for the proxy listener to be able to negotiate SSL connections.

PortSwigger have written documentation for this:

- https://portswigger.net/burp/documentation/desktop/tools/proxy/options/installing-ca-certificate
- https://support.portswigger.net/customer/portal/articles/1783075-installing-burp-s-ca-certificate-in-your-browser